# Appium tests on AWS Device Farm not executing in the specified order

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-android, aws-device-farm

My tests are working fine when i run them locally on appium. But when i run the tests on AWS Device Farm, the desired order of execution is not followed. I have used @Tests(priority=1) etc,. but tests are not executing in order.
New session is created for every @Test method in amazon device farm.

The desired execution order is -  BeforeGroup BeforeMethod1 AfterMethod1 BeforeMethod2 AfterMethod2 BeforeMethod3 AfterMethod3 AfterGroup

But on AWS Device Farm, the order is - BeforeGroup BeforeMethod1 AfterMethod1 AfterGroup (after which teardown happens)

Can anyone tell me a way to overcome this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected in the standard environment for Device Farm. However there is a workaround that I've developed here.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/issues/15#issuecomment-397845385

Alternatively, the project might benefit from the custom environments in Device Farm

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html

That should allow priority to be honored in Device Farm.

Hth
  -James